# Ubuntu 20.4 Slow Wifi issue

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, dell, intel

I have recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 3501(i5 11th Gen), windows 10 was preinstalled with the machine . I was testing out the machine with Win10 for 2 days and everything was working good . I have installed latest Ubuntu 20.4 on this machine , everything went well except Wifi . I am using a 100Mbps connection and I used to get above 30Mbps consistently when I was using Windows on same machine . I have tried all the options available in this portal and stack overflow and other sites (Upgrading kernel , changing router settings,wifi power settings etc) . Still the Wifi speed to too bad

The machine is using QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter . Can we install Intel network  driver instead of Qualcom . Does anybody facing this issue in any of the Dell laptop or other brands which is using Qualcom . Does going back to 18.04 will help in this scenario.

Note: I found many questions around the slowness of the Wifi ,but none of the answers where helpful for my use case